# How to test if an Observable has published an event or not before exiting a Jasmine test?

Tags: angular, jasmine, observable

If I have a scenario like this:

```
it('some observable', /*done*/() => {
    
    const someService = TestBed.get(SomeService);

    const subscription = someService.someObservable.subscribe(value => {
        expect(value).toEqual('some value');
        subscription.unsubscribe();
        /*done();*/
    });

    // This method is supposed to cause the Observable to publish the value to all subscribers.
    someService.setValue('some value');
});
```

How can I fail the test if the Observable never publishes an event? This scenario has a couple problems. First, if the Observable never publishes the event, the done() method never gets called. Also, if it doesn't publish the event, how will my test know? It won't look like a failure, Jasmine will just print that the test has no 'expect' or something like that.

**Update**: I've realized that I don't need the done() function because I'm resetting the TestBed before each test now. But that still doesn't solve the problem when if an Observable doesn't fire, the test won't fail.

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned, I think you can take advantage of the `done` function.

```
it('some observable', (done) => { // put done in the callback
    
    const someService = TestBed.get(SomeService);

    const subscription = someService.someObservable.subscribe(value => {
        expect(value).toEqual('some value');
        done(); // call done to let jasmine know that you're done with the test
    });

    // This method is supposed to cause the Observable to publish the value to all subscribers.
    someService.setValue('some value');
});
```

If the observable doesn't publish any events, `done` won't get called and the test will hang with an `async timeout error`.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem like a great strategy for running unit tests on a release train. Isn't there any other way to know that an Observable never fired an event?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48389737/unit-testing-that-items-get-filtered-out-of-observable-jasmine-rxjs Check that out, maybe it can be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I ended up doing it:

```
it('some observable', () => {
    
    const someService = TestBed.get(SomeService);

    const someValue = 'some value';
    const spy = jasmine.createSpy('someSpy');

    const sub = someService.someObservable.subscribe(spy);
    someService.setValue(someValue);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(someValue);
    sub.unsubscribe();
});
```

I'm not sure why this works because I thought Observables were async. But it seems to be working without worrying about async. Maybe I'm just getting lucky and the problem will rear its ugly head later.