# RxJS: Check for NEVER?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, rxjs6

I have a problem with fixing the unit test of the code that returns `NEVER` (`new Observable<never>()`).

My problem is, that I don't even know how to test for that, as `NEVER` will never run any function inside `subscribe`. As this is async code, I cannot test in outside of the method, because it has tendency to **sometimes** run in `afterAll` and that breaks the tests - random crashes.

Generally for async methods with `Observables` I normally use functions within `subscribe` method.

Ex.

```
myFunction.subscribe(
  next => {
     fail();
  },
  error => { 
    expect(error).toBe(myError);
    done();
  },
  () => { 
    fail();
    done();
  });
```

This pretty work well with testing the async code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48390467/7365461 I think that link can possibly help you.

Comment: It is a sort of philosophical question. How to be sure that something never happens? Probably the best you can say is "up to this moment, that thing did not happen". So, if this premise holds, the best you can do is to use your code snippet and add a `settimeout` where you execute the `done` function after an arbitrary amount of time.

Comment: You can check the affected functions and set and spy to check `not.toHaveBeenCalled()` on all those who can be triggered when its not `NEVER`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so based on all the comments I received (and of course my own tests) it looks like there is no way to check returned `Observable` if it's `NEVER`. Nothing special while inspecting the object.

There is indeed constant called `NEVER` in `rxjs`, but in the behind it creates `new Observable<never>(noop())`  so it cannot be compared.

So as a final approach I came with solution:

```
myFunction.pipe(
    timeoutWith(3000, of('timed-out'))
  )
  .subscribe(
    next => {
      expect(next).toBe('timed-out');
    },
    error => {
      fail(error);
      done();
    },
    () => {
      expect(someInjectedClass.someFunction).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      done();
    }
  );
```